# Is the variety a closed subscheme of the fibered product?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a surface over $\mathbb{C}$. And let $L$ be an ample line bundle on $S$. Let $C\in |L|$ be a smooth curve. And Let $A$ be a globally generated ample line bundle on $C$ with $n+1$ sections, that is $h^0(C,A)=n+1$. I have these doubts.

A) Is $C$ a closed subscheme of $X=\mathbb{P}^n_S =\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}\times S$. Here I know that $C$ is a closed subscheme of both $S$ as well as $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ (by means of $A$). But is $S$ or $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ a closed subscheme of $X$?

B) Also we have the projection map $\mathbb{P}^n_S\longrightarrow S$. What is the image of $C$ under this projection? It is just $C$ right?

These are possibly trivial questions, but they have been niggling me for a while. Thank you!

Comment: The mapping to projective space induced by $A$ need not be an embedding. And what kind of "divisor" is $D$?

Comment: It is an irreducible closed subvariety of codimension 1. When will $D$ be a subvariety of the projective space?

Comment: Well, $D$ has to be projective and $A$ has to be very ample. There are tests for this depending on the situation but nothing is automatic.

Comment: @Hoot, if $S$ is a surface, $L$ is an ample line bundle on $S$ and $C\in |L|$ is a smooth curve. Let $A$ be a very ample line bundle with $n+1$ global sections. In such a case I would like to know if $C$ is a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n_S$. How do I go about checking that? Thanks!